# List of all objects with labels and API names

Tags: salesforce, visualforce, apex, soql

I am looking for a way to get list of all objects with the labels and the API names, to be displayed on visual force page.

Any ideas or samples on how to achieve this. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

If you are displaying the Objects in SelectList and their labels [Check this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/48920/dynamic-picklists-of-objects-its-fields/48936#48936) . You can alse display the API Names. 
[Check this also](http://jungleeforce.wordpress.com/2013/06/07/extracting-list-of-all-the-objects-standard-custom-in-salesforce/)